# Receiving JMS messages via Spring integration inbound adapter randomly fails

Tags: spring, jms, spring-integration

I am new to this Spring Integration and JMS and i started playing with it. In here i want to create plain jms message via activemq and receive it through spring inbound adapter(message driven).

following is my spring config file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd>
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd">

<!-- jms beans -->
<beans:bean id="jms.msgQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="MSG_QUEUE" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean name="jms.connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <beans:property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
</beans:bean>


 <!-- spring integration beans -->
<channel id="channels.jms.allMessages">
    <queue capacity="1000" />
</channel>

<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="adapters.jms.msgAdapter"
            connection-factory="jms.connectionFactory"
            destination="jms.msgQueue"
             channel="channels.jms.allMessages" />
```

and this is my testing class

```
package com.bst.jms;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.integration.Message;
import org.springframework.integration.core.PollableChannel;

public class TestActiveMQ {

public static void main(String[] args){

    try{
        AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("app-context.xml");
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory)context.getBean("jms.connectionFactory");
        Destination destination = (Destination)context.getBean("jms.msgQueue");
        PollableChannel msgChannel = (PollableChannel) context.getBean("channels.jms.allMessages", PollableChannel.class );

        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);


        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);

         TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage();
         textMessage.setText("Message from JMS");
         producer.send(textMessage);


         System.out.println("--------------- Message Sending ------------------------");

         Message<?> received = msgChannel.receive();
         String payload = (String) received.getPayload();

         System.out.println("Receving message = " + payload);
    }catch(JMSException ex){
        System.out.println("----------- JMS Exception --------------");
    }

}
```

}

But the thing is i can not guarantee the delivery. some times the program can not receive the message and some tomes it succeeds with some warnings like

```
Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'queue://MSG_QUEUE' -   trying to recover. Cause: Connection reset
Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://MSG_QUEUE' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://MSG_QUEUE' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

This occurs few times before it succeeds.

Do you guys have any idea about this.

appreciate your help.

thanks,
keth

Answer (score 3):

This just means the broker isn't running when the listener container starts. When using a tcp:// URL you should run the broker in it's own context (or another JVM) before creating this context.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested these code in my STS its working fine .

The only problem in your side is , first start message Broker (say ActiveMQ) then run your project, you can get your required output.

Thanks.